# Strange behaviour migrating sessions with callbacks from php4 to php5

Tags: php, session, callback, migration, php4

I have to migrate a php4 app that uses `session_set_save_handler()` to php5.

In php4 everything was fine, but in php5 the callback functions cannot access the global vars anymore, which were set on the page before `session_set_save_handler()` was called.

In the example below the global var $g1 cannot be accessed in the `session_writer()` (which is passed as a callback function)

Is there some explanation for this behavior or can you give a hint on migrating sessions with callbacks from php4 to 5?

This is the pseudo code:

```
function session_writer($id,$vars) {
  global $g1;
  echo "g1 not defined here: ".is_object($g1);
}

global $g1;
$g1 = SomeObject(); //which is the DB connection for the session writer

session_set_save_handler($o,$c,$r,"session_writer",$d,$g);
session_start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually noted in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php):

> As of PHP 5.0.5 the write and close handlers are called after object destruction and therefore cannot use objects or throw exceptions. The object destructors can however use sessions.
>
> It is possible to call `session_write_close()` from the destructor to solve this chicken and egg problem.

Essentially, you'll have to call `session_write_close()` from the destructor of your `SomeObject`, or alternatively, do the following:

```
<?php register_shutdown_function("session_write_close"); ?>
```

Either of those solutions should force the writing and closing of the session before all objects are destroyed, allowing you to keep your original callback function.

Comment: Thank you, I am beginning to grasp what is happening here. SomeObject() is my Database. So I could refactor and copy the creation of the DB object to the session_writer itself, this would be easiest?

Comment: No, they actually cannot use objects at all, unless you force the writing of the session *before* the objects are destroyed. As I said, you should call session_write_close() from some object destructor OR register it as shutdown function.

Answer (score 0):

Molf's answer identifies the problem. Here's some more info:

`session_write_close()` takes as input an identifier and the data associated with it.  If you're going for minimal change, you'll probably need to know the data is what is returned by `session_encode()` (which is a string encoding the contents of the $_SESSION array).  The identifier is what is returned by `session_id()`.