# From PHP4 to PHP5:session handler can't access global DB object

Tags: php, session

I am migrating a PHP app written many, many years ago in PHP 4.4 to a new host that runs PHP 5.3. The app was written using only the PEAR libraries and no other framework. I'm finding the following problem: I have in my main page this code:

```
require_once('DB.php'); //the PEAR DB package

$db=DB::connect("mysql://usuario:@localhost/databasename");
if (DB::isError($db)) {
    die("MEEEEEPT");
    }

//Inicia sesión
session_set_save_handler("Sesion_Open", "Sesion_Close", "Sesion_Read", "Sesion_Write", "Sesion_Delete", "Sesion_Clean");
session_name("misesion");
session_start();
```

And then, the session handlers are:

```
function Sesion_Open() {

    global $db;

    if (DB::isConnection($db)) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
    }

function Sesion_Close() {

    global $db;

    $db->disconnect();
    return true;
    }

function Sesion_Read($id) {

    global $db;

    $resultado=$db->query("SELECT datos FROM sesiones WHERE id='$id'");
    $num=$resultado->numRows();
    if ($num > 0) {
        $row=$resultado->fetchRow(DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
        $resultado->free();
        return $row['datos'];
        }
    else {
        $resultado->free();
        return "";
        }
    }

function Sesion_Write($id, $datos) {

    global $db;

    $datos=addslashes($datos);
    $num=$db->getOne("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM sesiones WHERE id='$id'");
    if ($num > 0) {
        $sql="UPDATE sesiones SET datos='$datos', tiempo=now() WHERE id='$id'";
        }
    else {
        $sql="INSERT INTO sesiones (id, tiempo, datos) VALUES ('$id', now(), '$datos')";
        }
    $resultado=$db->query($sql);
    if (DB::isError($resultado)) { return false; }
    else { return true; }
    }
```

If I try to save some data in the session, using, say:

```
$_SESSION['bkla']="Doremifa";
```

It doesn't get saved: the DB sessions table remains empty, and I get an error in the log saying:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getOne() on a non-object in sesiones.php on line 45
```

Referring to the line in "Sesion_Write" where I try to do a SELECT on the table.

From what I see, the "Sesion_Open" function can access correctly the $db object, but the others can't see it; the object doesn't seem to exist for them. What's going on? I haven't touched PHP in a few years, so I don't know if something changed between PHP4 and PHP5 to cause this, or there's something else.

Comment: Off-hand, try marking `$db` as global when you connect to the database, eg: `global $db = DB::connect(`

Comment: @bishop: Nope, that didn't work. In fact, doing `global $db = DB::connect(` gives me a parse error. I had to do a `global $db` in a separate line before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found the answer:

[Strange behaviour migrating sessions with callbacks from php4 to php5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084893/strange-behaviour-migrating-sessions-with-callbacks-from-php4-to-php5)

You need to either call `session_write_close()` by hand, or register it as a shutdown function: `register_shutdown_function("session_write_close")`.

Comment: Hmm, weird, didn't know about that. Glad you found a solution!